# How do I delete a field from my Django ModelForm?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to hide and delete two fields from showing in a form I created in the Django administration page using ModelForm.
I looked at answers that said I should use the "exclude" meta field, but I don't know why it's not working in my case.
Here is my code:

models.py:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="owner")
    college = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    startDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    endDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    attendee = models.ManyToManyField(Attendee, related_name="attendees",null=True, blank=True)
    volunteer = models.ManyToManyField(Volunteer, related_name="volunteers",null=True, blank=True)
```

I'm trying to exclude the "attendee & volunteer" fields from displaying in the Django administration form.

In admin.py I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from KSUvity.models import Activity


class ActivityForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        exclude = ['attendee', 'volunteer',]

class ActivityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['attendee', 'volunteer',]
    form = ActivityForm

admin.site.register(Activity, ActivityAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an admin.py file in your app and register your models
Follow the [instuctions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form)
See the example below

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Person

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ['name']

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['age']
    form = PersonForm

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

Comment: Check my updated code in my question. I followed the exact same steps but nothing changed and the fields are still showing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either fields or exclude in one class.

In your app admin field add this code.

> app_name/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin


class ActivityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('attendee', 'volunteer',)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options) option to exclude fields from form in Django administration, either `ModelAdmin.exclude` or `ModelAdmin.fields`. Below is an example:

```
class ActivityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('attendee', 'volunteer', )
```

To make it work, you register model like this:

```
admin.site.register(Activity, ActivityAdmin)
```

You add this code to `admin.py` file.

Comment: I added this code in admin.py but nothing changed, the fields are still showing in the form.

Comment: To make it work, you need to register model like this `admin.site.register(Activity, ActivityAdmin)`. But I see you already got it working.